# C++ Convert Lat Long to BNG with Proj.4

Tags: c++, proj

Im creating a plugin for VBS2. In the program I can output a grid in either LAT LONG,UTM or MGRS. I need to be able to  convert to BNG. I have managed to create a TKinter application in python that works using Proj.4 but now need to create it in C++ as a DLL.

The LatLong im using (51.20650N 1.81906W) is a known point, the BNG conversion is approx SU 127 452.

```
#include <proj_api.h>




double x = 51.20650; //atof(GetStrArgument(input, 0)); 
double y = 1.81906;  //atof(GetStrArgument(input, 1));  

char *pj_latlongc = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84";
char *pj_UTMc = "+proj=utm +zone=29 +ellps=WGS84";
char *osc = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

projPJ pj_OS = pj_init_plus(osc);
projPJ pj_UTM = pj_init_plus(pj_UTMc);
projPJ pj_latlong = pj_init_plus(pj_latlongc);

x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

int p = pj_transform(pj_latlong, pj_OS, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL);
```

Unfortunately the result is completely wrong and doesn't make sense.Could someone help on this?

Comment: Did you try to test the same point with the executables shipped with proj.4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching x for y and flipping the sign of x seems to yield better results. Running those numbers on the console, the `proj` output seems to agree better with [the point you specified (51.20650N 1.81906W)](https://goo.gl/maps/MvFJE)

```
echo -1.81906 51.20650 | proj -V +proj=tmerc
Longitude: 1d49'8.616"W [ -1.81906 ]
Latitude:  51d12'23.4"N [ 51.2065 ]
```

Similarly, `cs2cs` returns seemingly sensible output:

```
echo -1.81906 51.20650 | cs2cs -v +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84   +to   +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs
# ---- From Coordinate System ----
#Lat/long (Geodetic alias)
#
# +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
# ---- To Coordinate System ----
#Transverse Mercator
# Cyl, Sph&Ell
# +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000
# +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs
# +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894
#--- following specified but NOT used
# +ellps=airy
412736.92  145270.05 -47.95
```

This is identical to the C++ program's output

```
double x = -1.81906;
double y = 51.20650;
412736.924409  145270.054358
```

For comparison, I ran the numbers through the [BNG converter of the British Geological Survey](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/data/webservices/convertForm.cfm), which seems to agree as well

```
Easting: 412737
Northing: 145270
```

For writing these numbers in the form of an [Ordnance Survey National Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid) reference, just subtract integer multiples of 100km to derive the corresponding letter as illustrated in this [Source Code for JavaScript](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/blob/master/osgridref.js#L240). The final result is `SU 127 452`, as desired:

```
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  double x = -1.81906;
  double y = 51.20650;

  const char* pj_latlongc = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84";
  const char* osc = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

  projPJ pj_latlong = pj_init_plus(pj_latlongc);
  projPJ pj_OS = pj_init_plus(osc);

  x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
  y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

  int p = pj_transform(pj_latlong, pj_OS, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL);

  std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::showpoint);
  std::cout << x << "  " << y << std::endl;;
  // prints 412736.924409  145270.054358


  // now convert to UK Grid Ref
  int e1 = floor(x/100000);
  int n1 = floor(y/100000);
  int e2 = (int)x % 100000 / 100;
  int n2 = (int)y % 100000 / 100;
  char l1 = (19 - n1) - (19-n1) % 5 + ((e1 + 10)/5);
  char l2 = (19 - n1) * 5 % 25 + e1 % 5;
  if (l1 > 7) l1++;
  if (l2 > 7) l2++;
  l1 = 'A' + l1;
  l2 = 'A' + l2;

  std::cout << l1 << l2 << ' ' << e2 << ' ' << n2 << std::endl;
  // prints SU 127 452
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this help, i have not had a chance to try it yet although looking through it, it makes sense. ill re-comment as soon as i get a chance to check